# Better to use if(someVar) or if (someVar == true)

Tags: comparison, compare

We are having a discussion about what is considered best practice, when checking expressions.

So what is considered to be best practice if(someVar) or if(someVar == true)?

Is there any situation, where it would mess up, if we just write if (someVar)?

Comment: No you won't mess up anything, but you should get used to write if (someVar). It's shorter and more readable.

Comment: `if(someVar === true)` is the best practice. And only this.

Comment: well, what language is it ? and what is the type of someVar ... in some cases someVar == true might even be false when someVar is TRUE, 0 or #undef or...

Comment: We are just talking in general - could see it making a difference in languages, that use 3 === for comparing?

Comment: I'm not immediately aware of any language that has a `===` operator...

Answer (score 0):

Use `if (somevar)` and `if(!somevar)` 
or
`if(somevar == true)` and `if(somevar == false)`

I'ts a personal taste, but I prefer the first one, the old C style